# ¿Como implementar un dataset de pixeles de imagenes personalizado en tensorflow?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, inteligencia-artificial

Tengo un dataset (que creo que está mal pero luego lo voy a arreglar), que almacena los pixeles de imagenes y la etiqueta, y quiero usar una inteligencia artificial similar a mnist, o fashio_mnist, el dataset es similar a esto:

### pixeles|

2,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00...|
1,0.97,0.97,0.97,0.97,0.97,0.97,0.97,0.97,0.97,0.97,0.97...|
0,0.30,0.31,0.31,0.32,0.33,0.34,0.35,0.36,0.36,0.36,0.36...|
1,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00...|

Creo que está mal porque segun he leido se deberían tener pixeles en RGB, y yo los tengo en escala de grises limitados a 0 y 1, pero idependientemente del contenido del dataset, supongo que se trabajaría igual con la excepción de las normalizaciones.

El problema es que no se muy bien como trabajar con el dataset, consiguo los datos y separo el primer valor, pero luego de eso no se como continuar, y como alguien que no tiene mucha idea de python estoy perdido en ese punto.

Me baso en el modelo que se contruye en la guía de tensorflow, sobre tu primer red neuronal, en la que usan fashio_mnist.

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('/dataset.csv', sep=';')

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
pixeles = dataset['pixels'].str.split(pat=',', expand=True, n=-1)
tags = pixeles.pop(0)
pixeles = pixeles.astype(np.float32)
tags = tags.values.astype(int)

for i in range(len(pixeles)):
  pixeles[i].reshape(48,48)
  pixeles[i] = np.array(pixeles[i])

plt.imshow(pixeles[5].reshape(48, 48), cmap='gray')
plt.show()

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 32

model.fit(datos_entrenamiento, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(numero_imagenes_entrenamiento/batch_size))

test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(pixeles, steps=math.ceil(numero_imagenes_prueba/batch_size))
print('Lost: ', test_loss)
print('Accuracy on test dataset:', test_accuracy)
```

Segín leí en algunas páginas y ví ejemplos no debería haber cabecera, pero no se manejar el dataset sin cabecera.

Como puden ver, el numero de entrenamiento y de prueba no están definidos, directamente no se como hacerlo, y siempre que entro a buena documentación me pierdo más, aunque, a está
[página](https://interactivechaos.com/es/manual/tutorial-de-deep-learning/lectura-del-dataset-mnist) le logré comprender algo.

Y dejo mi [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O7Jw3OAUkzePSLrccEGbwNJOXJ4YhNtd/view?usp=sharing), que de seguro está malo, una disculpa si les duelen los ojos, hice eso con lo poco que se de python.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lo conseguí casi por completo, me guíe en base a [este post](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/experiment-on-neural-networks-with-mnist-dataset-dc276377334a), expecificamente el primer modelo que se hace, pues tengo poco tiempo, pero si no me funciona probaré con los demás.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential

data_train = pd.read_csv('/content/train.csv')
data_test = pd.read_csv('/content/test.csv')

x_train = data_train.copy()
label = x_train['label']
x_train.drop(['label'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
x_train.head()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
train = model.fit(x_train, label.values.reshape(42000,1),batch_size=32, epochs=500,validation_split=.3)

pred = model.predict(data_test)
pred = pred.round(0)

print(pred)

test = data_test.copy()
test = tf.convert_to_tensor(test.values)
img = np.array(test[8])
img = img.reshape(784,1)

prd = model.predict(np.expand_dims(np.array(img, dtype=np.float32), 0))
print(prd)
```

**NOTA** Si no me equivoco, `label.values.reshape(42000,1)` hace referencia a la cantidad de valores del dataset, los csv los pueden descargar de [está página](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/data)

Comment: Ok, para hacer solo una predicción es de la siguiente manera `prd = model.predict(np.expand_dims(np.array(img, dtype=np.float32), 0))` donde `img` será el array de la imagen

Comment: Puedes editar tu respuesta y agregar eso :D

Comment: @Christian Listo ;)